Can we pass an array to func(), instead of just passing in the parameters?
I need to call a function and I need pass its parameters in a dynamic way:
params := ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
func("myFunc").Call(params)

I am intending for the above mean the "literal" equivalent of myFunc("param1", "param2", "param3") but when I run the code, the function does not receive any parameters but it does with something like this:
params := ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
func("myFunc").Call(params[1], params[2], params[3])

Currently I am doing something like this, which is not ideal:
params := ["param1", "param2", "param3"]

if (params.MaxIndex() = 1)
    func("myFunc").Call(params[1])
else if (params.MaxIndex() = 2)
    func("myFunc").Call(params[1], params[2])
else if (params.MaxIndex() = 3)
    func("myFunc").Call(params[1], params[2], params[3])

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Seems doable: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=103903

@PaulT. I found an "official" way to do it. Shared it as anwer.

GroggyOtter over at Reddit helped me with the answer, I will share it here just in case.
I simply had to add * to the end of the variable name to invoke the function variadic style:
params := ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
func("myFunc").Call(params*) ; is the literal version of typing -->  func("myFunc").Call("param1, param2, param3)

